# Jekyll-Twitter-Plugin urls and new lines not showing correctly

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm quite new to jekyll and don't know where the problem could be. I used the jekyll-twitter-plugin to create an twitterfeed on my site.

I just implemented the basic code like this .

```
<div class='jekyll-twitter-plugin' align="center">
  {% twitter https://twitter.com/example maxwidth=500%}
</div>
```

The twitter feed is working correctly, but when I tweet something the url is shown (it's not shown on the normal twitter site) and some new lines in the original are ignored.

How can I fix this?